# How to enable 'fling scrolling' in a TextView

Tags: android, scroll, textview

My TextView scrolls only when the finger is in contact with the screen and only for the distance which the finger moved. How to enable fling scrolling in the TextView?

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/helloWorld"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".HelloWorld" 
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
    android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/scrollBarSize"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="2000"/>
```

I found some sample code here:
[Vertical fling scrolling of text line in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422697/vertical-fling-scrolling-of-text-line-in-android)
Please tell me there is a better way to do this!

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Here you don't want to use a `ScrollView` .

Just use the following lines in xml file

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your `TextView` in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

in your java code.

Comment: This doesn't enable fling scrolling (just "regular" scrolling as far as the finger is moved) and is also almost an exact copy of the response http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/1016939 ...